# rake task can't access rails.cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, rake

I want to call a rake task from a cron job that stores remote weather data in the rails cache. However, I must be doing something pretty wrong here because I cannot find any solution through countless fruitless searches.

Say I define and call this task

```
namespace :weather do
  desc "Store weather from remote source to cache"
  task :cache do
    Rails.cache.write('weather_data', Date.today)
  end
end
```

I get the error

```
Anonymous modules have no name to be referenced by
```

Which leads me to believe the rails cache isn't available. Outputting Rails.class from the rake file gives me Module but Rails.cache.class again returns the above error. Do I need to include something here? Am I just hopeless at internet? :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try passing in the rails environment

```
task (:cache => :environment) do
    ...
end
```

seems like you would get a different error, but I would try this