# Using ActiveRecord::Base.transaction in a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, yaml

I am writing a rake task which, at one point, uses a custom YAML file import method to seed the database.

The rake task looks like:

```
desc "Seed the database with production/ data."
task :production => :environment do     
  import_yaml 'seed/production'
end
```

At one point in the import code, I have:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
```

Trying to run the rake task throws:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
```

The stack trace points to the aforementioned line in the code.

Is there a way to instantiate ActiveRecord::Base during a rake task?

Thanks!

Comment: This should definitely include code or at least a sample. Also, the question title does not relate to the problem, nor solution....

Comment: It should, right? 7 years later I don't recall what the actual issue / solution was. Would delete this question if I could but it won't allow me to because someone wrote an answer.

Answer (score 3):

maybe you have not included the 'environment' in the rake task?

[rake task can't access rails.cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791321/rake-task-cant-access-rails-cache/2791337)

```
task (:my_rake_task => :environment) do
    # ....
end
```

without the => :environment you will not have access to any of your rails app models